# Getting Order Cost from Order Line in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

In my cube I have a **Fact Order Line**, which has variable **Order Cost**. This variable is for course unique per Order and has the same value in every Order Line of an Order.

Now I want to create a calculated field that sums the **Order Cost**, but only takes this value once for every order.

So, using the calculated member this

```
+-------------------+--------------+------------+            
| Order Line Number | Order Number | Order Line |
|                   |              | Order Cost |
+-------------------+--------------+------------+
|                10 |            1 | $0.20      |
|                11 |            1 | $0.20      |
|                20 |            2 | $0.25      |
+-------------------+--------------+------------+
```

has to become this

```
+--------------+------------+
| Order Number | Order Cost |
+--------------+------------+
|            1 | $0.20      |
|            2 | $0.25      |
+--------------+------------+
```

The MDX expression I currently have (see below), sums over the order line, making the **Order Cost** $0.40 for Order Number 1.

```
SUM( 
    DISTINCT( 
        CROSSJOIN(
            [Order Line Details].[Order Number].[All].Children, [Measures].[Order Line Order Cost]
        )
    )
)
```

**What do I need to change to get the desired behavior?**

Please let me know if there is anything unclear regarding the question.

**Solution**

Ok, I found the problem. I changed the Aggregate Behaviour from the [Measures].[Order Line Order Cost] to min. After that you initial solution worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the below work? I have got rid of unnecessary `crossjoin`, and put the `distinct` function on the `[Order Line Details].[Order Number].Children` and used the `SUM` function to add up the `Order Line Order Cost` against the order numbers.

```
SUM(
    DISTINCT([Order Line Details].[Order Number].Children)
    , [Measures].[Order Line Order Cost]
   )
```

**EDIT**
Try the below code:

```
WITH
SET DistinctOrderNumbers AS
DISTINCT(EXISTING [Order Line Details].[Order Number].Children)

MEMBER [Measures].[Order Cost] AS 
SUM(DistinctOrderNumbers, [Measures].[Order Line Order Cost]) 

SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Order Cost] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([Reseller].[Reseller].[Reseller].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
FROM [BI Cube]
```

**EDIT2 (avg not sum)**

```
WITH
SET DistinctOrderNumbers AS
DISTINCT(EXISTING [Order Line Details].[Order Number].Children)

MEMBER [Measures].[Order Cost] AS 
AVG(DistinctOrderNumbers, [Measures].[Order Line Order Cost]) 

SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Order Cost] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([Reseller].[Reseller].[Reseller].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
FROM [BI Cube]
```

Comment: No, it still sums the [Order Line Order Cost] over all Order Lines.

Comment: What is the entire MDX query you are using?

Comment: `WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Order Cost] AS SUM(DISTINCT([Order Line Details].[Order Number].Children), [Measures].[Order Line Order Cost])
 SELECT 
 NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Order Cost] } ON COLUMNS, 
 NON EMPTY { ([Reseller].[Reseller].[Reseller].ALLMEMBERS ) } ON ROWS 
 FROM [BI Cube] `

Comment: It returns the same result.

Comment: @Raymond - I think you are looking for an average here, not sum. Try the Edit2

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. I changed the Aggregate Behaviour from the [Measures].[Order Line Order Cost] to min. After that you initial solution worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

```
MIN( 
    [Order Line Details].[Order Number].[All].Children
   ,[Measures].[Order Line Order Cost]
    )
```